# What is the keyboard shortcut for "Fit page to current window" in Visio 2010?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2010

It used to be Ctrl + k in older versions of Visio, now that command closes the current document which, as you can imagine, is incredibly annoying after the 10th or 11th time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fit to window (Visio 2010): <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

Source: [Keyboard shortcuts for Microsoft Office Visio 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/visio-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-office-visio-HP010357062.aspx).